# Wordpress sql fetch_assoc

Tags: sql, wordpress

I'm having hard time troubleshooting why i cannot seem to run this inside wordpress like on the index.php. It works when its standalone. I created additional table inside wordpress db. Im seeing blank data when i run. Somehow its not picking up the data. I came to know after research i need to use  $wpdb and get_results. so I converted it from this old code :

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT name,rating FROM wp_figure where status = '1' ORDER BY rating DESC");
```

/**to wordpress code**/

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT name,rating FROM wp_figure where status = '1' ORDER BY rating DESC");
?>
```

//on the header.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['name', 'Rating'],
      <?php
      if($result->num_rows > 0){
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "['".$row['name']."', ".$row['rating']."],";
          }
      }
      ?>
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Figure',
        width: 900,
        height: 500,
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>

on the body html i have

<body>
    <!-- Display the pie chart -->
    <div id="piechart"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using $wpdb , then you must need to pass 'ARRAY_A' inside get_results like the following to get result in array format.

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT name,rating FROM wp_figure where status = '1' ORDER BY rating DESC",'ARRAY_A');
```

Comment: Thank you Ahmed... On the next php which is shown below Im getting blank. How do I convert it to wordpress compatible.                             'code' <?php
      if($result->num_rows > 0){
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "['".$row['name']."', ".$row['rating']."],";
          }
      }
      ?>